# Can I reprogram the pwd command to add a trailing slash?

Tags: bash, alias, pwd

WHen I use the `pwd` command, it prints e.g `/opt` instead of `/opt/`. I would like it to print the trailing slash. However, I tried adding the following line to my `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias pwd=" echo "${PWD}/" "
```

But it doesn't work properly. Instead of printing my present working directory with a trailing slash, it prints the working directory I was in **at the start of the terminal session**, or at the last time I ran the `source ~/.bashrc` command. Even when I name the command something different, like `cwd`, it still behaves this way.

So - my question is, can I have some way to have an alias that prints my present working directory, followed by a trailing slash?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be better to write a function that checks for `$PWD`=`/`, because you don't want it to say "`//`" in that case.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that the `$PWD` part of your alias definition is unquoted (you close the double quoted string just before `$PWD` and then start a new one just afterwards).  This means that it is evaluated when the alias is defined.

Instead, use single quotes around *the whole* alias text, or even better<sup>*</sup>, use a shell function to override the `pwd` command.

Like so (or using `echo` if you must):

```bash
alias pwd='printf "%s/\n" "$PWD"'
```

Or, with a shell function:

```bash
pwd () {
    printf '%s/\n' "$PWD"
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Better = avoids complicated quoting, but still works the same way as you'd expect.

Comment: Root directory handling `pwd() { [[ $PWD = / ]] && echo / || printf '%s/\n' "$PWD"; }` or `pwd() { local slash=/; [[ $PWD = / ]] && slash=""; printf '%s%s\n' "$PWD" "$slash"; }`